# Can reduceByKey be used for multiple values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, sparkcore

I have just started learning spark and scala and testing on some transformations and actions on RDDs.

I found that reduceByKey is used as follows:

```
rdd.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)
```

where in, it is taking a tuple of two values of same and combining them using addition operation.

Now my question is can't we add up more than two values at time or all the values with same key at a single time? Something like this:

```
rdd.reduceByKey((p, q, r, s) => p+q+r+s)
```

Why adding only two values? Adding more than two values can save a lot of computation also?

Answer (score 0):

Techically, spark could provide such API, but it wont be practically useful.

Reducing more values at a time is not necessarily faster. This may be true if Spark RDDs are column-based, but they are not. Spark is row-based.

Comment: Spark is row-based? RDDs I think you mean. DF, DS not.